# what is the optimal data structure for a pool container?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, connection-pooling

At the moment i use the STL vector container template to put back and get the connections.

1) on get, a connection is returned and "erase()"d from pool vector.

2) on release, the connection is handed back to the pool via "push_back()".

This might be very heavy if the pool is frequently used. So my question is, is there any way to improve the performance here by switching to an other data structure?

Comment: Rarely bottlenecks are were we suppose they are, so profiling is much better than trying to optimize around cluelessly.

Comment: sure thing - the profiling. but conceptual seen this is the right approach using a container, i guess...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- If you only append at the back and erase from the back, `vector` is fine.
- If you append and erase from both front and back, but never from the middle, use `deque`.
- If you frequently must insert into and erase from the middle, use `list`.
- Depending on your lookup and traversal requirements, `set` might be an alternative.

In any case, you should *profile* the performance; use a typedef for your main container so you can quickly switch and test the different options.

There may be other requirements which you aren't telling us but which are important for the choice of container:

- vector and deque are random-access containers; list and set are node-based. This affects iterator invalidation.
- vector, deque and list are sequence containers, while set is associative; this affects lookup by value.

Comment: I would also add that if the OP is not erasing from the back, he should consider this approach (i.e. always `pop_back` and `push_back`) - it's a pool, so I'm guessing that there is no *order* and it may be beneficial to always use the last item anyway...

Comment: @Nim: Good point - I didn't go into the ambient coding problem, but (also as in Juraj's answer) swapping elements around to make all access exclusively at one end is a fine idea. `vector` is the simplest and most economical container, so if code redesign makes it viable, that's always a good thing.

Comment: I know that this advice is what is traditionally given, but my own measurements suggest that it isn't really correct.  Unless copying is very expensive (`new` and `delete` in the copy constructor or assignment operator), if the typical number of elements isn't too large, `std::vector` will beat all of the others.  And the only reason for ever using `std::list` is to avoid iterator invalidation.  The lack of locality kills any performance advantage it might have otherwise.

Comment: @James: Very plausible - that's why you have to profile :-) The asymptotic guarantees unfortunately say nothing about real-world behaviour!

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` is probably the best container for pool. O(1) for insertion and you can also have O(1) for removal if you don't need to maintain order. You can just swap the last item with the item removed and shrink the vector. Also `std::vector` is pretty space efficient compared to other containers. Low memory consumption also means a better performance because of more CPU cache hits.

Answer (score 2):

Keep vector if you know the maximum number of connections possible in advance (see vector::reserve).

Otherwise use std::list.

At the end it also depends of your platform and the version of the compiler and libstdc++ used.

Comment: `std::list` means allocations for every insert.  this will not be faster than `std::vector`.